impossible to load certificate. Error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID in my own CA with Windows
I've created my own CA and I've generated a certificate with the template Web Server. I want to use in an application with tomcat. I load the pfx certificate in my Tomcat but when I'm trying to load the URL in the client it says me:
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I've done these tutorial https://www.miniorange.com/guide-to-setup-ldaps-on-windows-server to generate LDAPS with certificate, and now I'm trying to use the same method to generate tomcat certificate but doesn't works.
Any help?
Thanks
Resolve problem of the certificates

That error means the certificate you issued doesn't include the hostname (domain) you're browsing. Check the cert info from your browser

Thanks @the_nuts, in the template I include the CN only. In CN, I put the FQDN of the tomcat server. It's a  Linux server. What's the domain field (domain component) ?
